# Why is `#[no_mangle]` required to see Rust functions in WASM library?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I created a new empty Rust library. I set the `crate-type` to `cdylib` so that `.wasm` files are generated. This is my `lib.rs`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn fibonacci(n: usize) -> usize {
  if n < 2 {
     return n;
  }

  return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

If I remove `#[no_mangle]`, then Cargo produces a WASM binary that doesn't even contain any code:

```
$ wasm-objdump -h -x target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/fibonacci.wasm

fibonacci.wasm: file format wasm 0x1

Sections:

    Table start=0x0000000a end=0x0000000f (size=0x00000005) count: 1
   Memory start=0x00000011 end=0x00000014 (size=0x00000003) count: 1
   Global start=0x00000016 end=0x0000002f (size=0x00000019) count: 3
   Export start=0x00000031 end=0x00000056 (size=0x00000025) count: 3
   Custom start=0x00000059 end=0x00000f5a (size=0x00000f01) ".debug_abbrev"
   Custom start=0x00000f5e end=0x0005c6df (size=0x0005b781) ".debug_info"
   Custom start=0x0005c6e3 end=0x00084461 (size=0x00027d7e) ".debug_ranges"
   Custom start=0x00084465 end=0x00118f6a (size=0x00094b05) ".debug_str"
   Custom start=0x00118f6e end=0x00152a48 (size=0x00039ada) ".debug_line"
   Custom start=0x00152a4a end=0x00152a63 (size=0x00000019) "name"
   Custom start=0x00152a65 end=0x00152ab2 (size=0x0000004d) "producers"
   Custom start=0x00152ab4 end=0x00152ae0 (size=0x0000002c) "target_features"

Section Details:

Table[1]:
 - table[0] type=funcref initial=1 max=1
Memory[1]:
 - memory[0] pages: initial=16
Global[3]:
 - global[0] i32 mutable=1 <__stack_pointer> - init i32=1048576
 - global[1] i32 mutable=0 <__data_end> - init i32=1048576
 - global[2] i32 mutable=0 <__heap_base> - init i32=1048576
Export[3]:
 - memory[0] -> "memory"
 - global[1] -> "__data_end"
 - global[2] -> "__heap_base"
Custom:
 - name: ".debug_abbrev"
Custom:
 - name: ".debug_info"
Custom:
 - name: ".debug_ranges"
Custom:
 - name: ".debug_str"
Custom:
 - name: ".debug_line"
Custom:
 - name: "name"
 - global[0] <__stack_pointer>
Custom:
 - name: "producers"
Custom:
 - name: "target_features"
  - [+] mutable-globals
  - [+] sign-ext
```

Is there any way to force the function to be included in the binary without using `#[no_mangle]`? Using `extern` by itself doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need `#[no_mangle]` anyway to be able to name the function, but it's weird that without it is omitted entirely.

Comment: `extern` just affects the ABI. In fact, not specifying an ABI just means the default ABI, which means it has no effects.

Comment: [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html?highlight=no_mangle#the-no_mangle-attribute), it is documented. Apparently it also implies [`used`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html?highlight=no_mangle#the-used-attribute).

Comment: Related: [Why does rust produce completely different assembly with and without pub and #\[no_mangle\]?](/q/55518419/2189130)

Comment: Does that mean that you should be able to just replace it with `used` and it could/should work?

Comment: @TachyonicBytes It will have a different (mangled) name, but yes, it will be exported.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't think so; I tried, but it is rejected (see the answer below).

Comment: @prog-fh Ah, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference says about [`no_mangle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html?highlight=no_mangle#the-no_mangle-attribute) that it obviously disables name mangling, but moreover it is similar to the [`used` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html?highlight=no_mangle#the-used-attribute).
However, `used` only applies to static items, not functions, as visible in the example below.

Then, the only way to export your function implies disabling name mangling (which is reasonable in my opinion).

```rust
fn this_is_invisible(n: i32) -> i32 {
    n * 2 + 1
}

pub fn this_is_also_invisible(n: i32) -> i32 {
    n * 2 + 1
}

#[no_mangle]
fn this_is_accepted(n: i32) -> i32 {
    n * 2 + 1
}

/*
// ERROR: attribute must be applied to a `static` variable
#[used]
fn this_is_rejected(n: i32) -> i32 {
    n * 2 + 1
}
*/
```

```
$ nm target/debug/libmy_project.so | grep this_is
0000000000006e00 T this_is_accepted
```

Answer (score 2):

`extern` is equivalent to `extern "C"` meaning the ABI of this function will use the common ABI of the platform (yes I refuse to call it C ABI).

`no_mangle` have two purposes, first disable the mangle, aka transforming the name of the function. And it will mark this function as "to export". Yes, it's maybe confusing. But `no_mangle` can be read as `export`.

See more:

- [The no_mangle attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html#the-no_mangle-attribute)

Comment: More precisely, public functions are always exported, but `#[no_mangle]` marks the function as "used", so the compiler won't remove it just because it isn't referenced in the code.